# Post form and get data on jQuery Dialog itself

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Currently i have my project which works this way

1. Keep Filling a form
2. Click on a button new window popups
3. fill data in popupwindow and submit
4. Popup window closes and data on that window is saved to database
5. Continue filling parent form and save the data

Now i want to replace the pop-up window with jQuery UI Dialog and perform the same operations
(Step 2 3 4)

Here some code

```
 $( "#rtrDialog" ).dialog({  
     autoOpen: false,     
     height: 300,
     modal: true,
     width: 350,  
     buttons: {        
         "Continue..": function() {
             alert("Button Clicked");
             var url = "contractDetails.htm";
             window.open(url, '_blank');
         }
     }
    });

$("#RTRButton").click(function(){
    $("#rtrDialog" ).dialog("open");
});


<!-- This form is used to capture the RTR related Dialogs -->

                        <div id="rtrDialog" title="Enter RTR Details">  
                        <form>  
                        <fieldset>    
                        <p><b>Enter Details for ?</b></p>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="applicant"/>Applicant<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="co-app1"/>Co-Applicant 1<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="co-app2" />Co-Applicant 2<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="co-app3" />Co-Applicant 3<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="guarantor1" />Guarantor 1<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="guarantor2" />Guarantor 2<br/>
                        <input type="radio" name="entity" value="guarantor3" />Guarantor 3<br/> 
                        </fieldset>  
                        </form>
                        </div>
```

How can i go about doing that   ??

Do i have to do the jQuery-Ajax way ? Or is there anything better to do this

Comment: I suggest you do the jquery ajax way, and use something like bootstrap twitter to make your dialog box; so yes you'll have to make some endpoints you can pass data to as API's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use twitter bootstrap for opening the dialog box and perform your action..
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

check this..
Hope this will help ..
```